# How to use extension with custom controller

Tags: controller, controller-extension, custom-controller

In my page, I get following error:

> Unknown constructor
>   'InstagramJsonToApexUserBio.InstagramJsonToApexUserBio(InstagramIntegration
>   controller)'

Here is my code:

```
<apex:page controller="InstagramIntegration" action="{!performOperation}" 
    extensions="InstagramJsonToApexUserBio" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to update extension's constructor to link it to the Controller.

If your controller is:

```
public class InstagramIntegration {

    // constructor
    public InstagramIntegration() {

    }
}
```

Extension would be like following (note the parameterized constructor):

```
public class InstagramJsonToApexUserBio {

    // constructor accepts main controller as a parameter in constructor
    public InstagramJsonToApexUserBio(InstagramIntegration objController) {

    }
}
```

Now it would allow you to save the page as it knows your extension is connected to the controller:

```
<apex:page controller="InstagramIntegration" 
    extensions="InstagramJsonToApexUserBio">
```